# How can I view a Twitter hashtag live stream?

Tags: twitter

We have a computer in the office dedicated to news updates. We would like to add a Twitter stream to it.

Unfortunately, if we try to look at a Twitter hashtag stream (https://twitter.com/hashtag/bitcoin?f=realtime) instead of it just showing the new results in real time, it shows a button you can click that says (x amount of new results).

How can I get Twitter to not prompt me to click a button every time new items come into the feed?

Comment: Is there a way for me to move this topic there?

Comment: Edited so that it does not violate bullet point number 7

Comment: You can probably make an userscript that automatically simulates a click on the button to load more tweets, or you can make a program that uses the [Stream API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/streaming) to display tweets matching a hashtag in real time.